# Problems making outgoing connections on Debian 8.7

Tags: networking, debian, hetzner

Please have patience, for I know not what I'm doing.

I have a server (at Hetzner.de) that otherwise run fine - reachable from where it needs to be reachable from and so on.

But - when I try to initiate connections to Hetzner's internal ressources via e.g. SCP or apt-get FROM said server, nothing happens, the command just hangs.

Internal ressources; the backup space on *.your-backup.de (accessible via SCP/SFTP) and internal debian repositories (mirror.hetzner.de)

Connecting to other servers I have at Hetzner, or other external stuff, works as expected. It's only the internal stuff that breaks.

However; if I do an 'sudo service networking restart', I can access both apt-get and the backup space (via SCP/SFTP) ... for a few minutes. Then it "breaks" again.

This problem exists only on this one server. I made a complete reinstall a few days ago, the problem was there before, and it's still there now.

I have UFW installed (and configured in 'paranoid' mode) and that was, of course, my first suspect. But disabling UFW does not change the behaviour.

Can anyone suggest anything I can try, to figure out what's wrong?

Comment: An incorrect subnet mask could easily cause this sort of behaviour.

Comment: First step would be to check DNS. Does it also hang if you resolve the hosts by hand and try connecting to the IP addresses ?

Comment: Hmm - I can SFTP to the IP address. I can also ping the hostname. But I cannot SFTP to the hostname.